# How can i use veriable in .where() - Firestore React Native ?

Tags: react-native, where-clause, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to reach user data from User Collection with using veriable in Where Query . And i use this code but the data did not retrieved:

```
export const userAddToOrganization = (email) => {  
    return (dispatch) => {
      if (email !== '') {
        console.log('email' , email); //'e@e.com √'
      firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("email", '==', `${email}`)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        });
      });
    }
    };
   };
```

When i use as **'e@e.com'**, the data retrieved successfuly. But i would like to use veriable (***email***)

```
 export const userAddToOrganization = (email) => {  
    return (dispatch) => {
      if (email !== '') {
        console.log('email' , email);
      firebase.firestore().collection('users').where("email", '==', 'e@e.com')
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
        });
      });
    }
    };
   };
```

How can i fetch the data with using veriable in WHERE Query. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const userAddToOrganization = (email) => {  
return (dispatch) => {
  if (email !== '') {
    console.log('email' , email); //'e@e.com √'
  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
   ref.where("email", '==', email)
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    });
  });
  }
 };
};
```

I haven't tested it, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Remove the string literal and pass the email directly. If that didn't work then I guess would be to trim the string, that removes all extra space.

```
export const userAddToOrganization = (email) => {  
return (dispatch) => {
  if (email !== '') {
    console.log('email' , email); //'e@e.com √'
  const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users')

  ref.where("email", '==', email.trim())
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
    });
  });
  }
 };
};
```

Comment: I updated my answer, try it out and let me know how it goes. @GökhanGeyik

Comment: I tried your updated answer, not worked :( and i have an error: cannot read property  trim()

Comment: use the first answer without trim()... I have the exact same and it's working for me. @GökhanGeyik

Comment: i think the problem was that email is not string it is object.  Because i send the email to actions as this.props. I changed it this.props.email then the problem solved. 

Thank you so much